# cannot encode json.decoded request body

Tags: go

I have a server implementation. Now I am writing unit test to check it's functionalities. 
I cannot prepare request, that would unmarshall on the server side well. Code below results with InvalidUnmarshallError. I don't know, how to debug it further.

Client side code:

```
    body := PatchCatRequest{Adopted: true}
    bodyBuf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    err := json.NewEncoder(bodyBuf).Encode(body)
    assert.NoError(t, err)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("PATCH", URL+"/"+catId, bodyBuf)
    recorder := httptest.NewRecorder()
    handler.PatchCat(recorder, req.WithContext(ctx))
```

Server side code:

```
type PatchCatRequest struct {
Adopted bool `json:"adopted"`
}

func (h *Handler) PatchCat (rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    var patchRequest *PatchCatRequest


if err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(patchRequest); err != nil {
    rw.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
    logger.WithField("error", err.Error()).Error(ErrDocodeRequest.Error())
    return
}
...
}
```

Comment: If you're getting an error, *include the error in your question*.

Comment: `InvalidUnmarshallError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unmarshaling into a nil pointer, as the error message says:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type PatchCatRequest struct {
    Adopted bool
}

func main() {
    var patchRequest *PatchCatRequest // nil pointer

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"Adopted":true}`), patchRequest)
    fmt.Println(err) // json: Unmarshal(nil *main.PatchCatRequest)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/vt7t5BgT3lA

Initialize the pointer before unmarshaling:

```
func main() {
    patchRequest := new(PatchCatRequest) // non-nil pointer

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"Adopted":true}`), patchRequest)
    fmt.Println(err) // <nil>
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/BqliguktWmr